# SQL query for Pricing analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Facing issue to find the Min and Max pricing status on the column YearMonth,

Below is my table data

```
   YearMonth    STATE   ProductGroup    LocaProdname    Price
    201407      MH      AIRTEL          AIRTEL-3G       10,000
    201208      GJ      IDEA            IDEA-3G         1,200
    201406      WB      AIRCEL          AIRCEL PERPAID  5,866
    201407      DL      TATA DOCOMA     TATA LANDLINE   8,955
    201207      KAR     VODAFONE        VODAFONE-3G     7,899
    201312      MH      AIRTEL          AIRTEL-3G       15,000
    201408      GJ      IDEA            IDEA-3G         25,000
```

I require below output:

```
YearMonth   STATE   ProductGroup    LocaProdname    Price   Indictor-YEAR
201407      MH      AIRTEL          AIRTEL-3G       10,000  MAX
201312      MH      AIRTEL          AIRTEL-3G       15,000  MIN
201408      GJ      IDEA            IDEA-3G         25,000  MAX
201208      GJ      IDEA            IDEA-3G         1,200   MIN
```

I need the Max yearmonth  and min Year values values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get values from first and last row per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group)

Comment: Need this in SQL-Server 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Row_number with partition BY and remove unwanted code as per your need,

```
SELECT yearmonth,state,productgroup,locaprodname,price,operation
    FROM   (
    SELECT * FROM   (SELECT p.yearmonth,p.state,p.productgroup,p.locaprodname,p.price,'MAX' AS Operation,
                           Row_number() OVER( partition BY p.productgroup, p.locaprodname
                               ORDER BY p.price DESC) AS Row
                    FROM   pricingtest p) AS Maxx
            WHERE  Maxx.row = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM   (SELECT p.yearmonth,p.state,p.productgroup,p.locaprodname,p.price,'MIN' AS Operation,
                           Row_number() OVER( partition BY p.productgroup, p.locaprodname
                               ORDER BY p.price ASC) AS Row
                    FROM   pricingtest p) AS Minn
            WHERE  Minn.row = 1

    ) AS whole
    ORDER  BY yearmonth,productgroup
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select YearMonth, STATE, ProductGroup, LocaProdname, Price,
       (case when seqnum_asc = 1 then 'MIN' else 'MAX' end) as Indicator
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by state, productgroup, localprodname
                                order by price asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by state, productgroup, localprodname
                                order by pricedesc) as seqnum_desc
      from data
     ) d
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1;
```

EDIT:

Does this do what you want?

```
select YearMonth, STATE, ProductGroup, LocaProdname, Price,
       (case when seqnum_asc = 1 then 'MIN' else 'MAX' end) as Indicator
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by YearMonth
                                order by price asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by YearMOnth
                                order by pricedesc) as seqnum_desc
      from data
     ) d
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1;
```

Comment: Not getting what exacly user requires , I need a out put where user can see the Max value of the YearMonth with the Price of that respective row.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by finding the MAX/MIN values associated with the `LocaProdname`,`ProductGroup` and `State` then joining in on the table where everything matches. See below, or view the fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d6bd/2

NOTE: I've added in `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` as you seem to only want ones which have changed price. (Ie. Have more than 1 entry)

```
SELECT p.YearMonth
    ,p.State
    ,p.ProductGroup
    ,p.LocaProdname
    ,p.Price
    ,CASE 
        WHEN p.Price = a.MaxPrice
            THEN 'MAX'
        WHEN p.Price = a.MinPrice
            THEN 'MIN'
        END AS [Indicator-YEAR]
FROM PricingTest p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LocaProdname
        ,ProductGroup
        ,State
        ,MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice
        ,MIN(Price) AS MinPrice
    FROM pricingTest
    GROUP BY LocaProdname
        ,ProductGroup
        ,State
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) a ON a.LocaProdname = p.LocaProdname
    AND a.ProductGroup = p.ProductGroup
    AND a.State= p.State
    AND (
        a.MaxPrice = p.Price
        OR a.MinPrice = p.Price
        )
ORDER BY LocaProdname
```

EDIT: Or I just noticed it's the max/min `YearMonth` the user might be looking, if this is the case check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d6bd/4 It is basically just replacing all references to `Price` to `YearMonth`.

Comment: I have edit as YearMonth wise but I need two records on for the single Product, That is min YearMonth with all values and Max YearMonth, now it showing all records for one product.

Comment: Did you check the sqlfiddle? It DOES show 2 lines for each product.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the last and first record you can UNION results:

```
SELECT t.*, 'MIN' AS Indicator
FROM 
  myTable t LEFT JOIN 
  myTable t2 ON t.YearMonth = t2.YearMonth AND t2.price < t.price
WHERE t2.YearMonth IS NULL
UNION
SELECT t.*, 'MAX' AS Indicator
FROM 
  myTable t LEFT JOIN 
  myTable t2 ON t.YearMonth = t2.YearMonth AND t2.price > t.price
WHERE t2.YearMonth IS NULL
```

If you have several records with same highest price, above query will return all of them. Also if you only have one record in a month, it will be returned twice as both MIN and MAX.