# Teradata First and Last Value

Tags: teradata

How to take first value and last value of a column with group by on a particuar column?
For eg:i need first_value and last_value of case_owner column based on group by og case id.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group

Comment: You can use the windows agg function like row_number() or rank() .

Answer (score 2):

For first value:

```
select case_owner  as case_owner_first_value
from
table
qualify row_number() over (partition by case_id  order by case_id) = 1
```

For last value:

```
select case_owner  as case_owner_last_value
from
table
qualify row_number() over (partition by case_id order by case_id desc ) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note, while combining the FIRST_VALUE with ORDER BY clause, you may need to add rows between.

Example:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE test_fv (id INTEGER,seq SMALLINT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO test_fv VALUES (NULL,1);
INSERT INTO test_fv VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO test_fv VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO test_fv VALUES (4,4);
INSERT INTO test_fv VALUES (5,5);

SELECT seq, FIRST_VALUE(id ignore NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY seq ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) FROM test_fv;
```

This wont work:

```
SELECT seq, FIRST_VALUE(id ignore NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY seq ASC) FROM test_fv;
```