# Filter varchar col from another col value in pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like below:

| object_key | created_by | updated_on | updated_by | attr_type | value_name | value_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 3/21/2021 | user1 | name | John |  |
| 1 | user4 | 4/15/2021 | user3 | mobile_number |  | 4567865 |
| 1 | user3 | 4/21/2021 | user2 | office_number |  | 2378783 |

I'm trying to pivot using the query:

```
SELECT object_key,
    max(created_on) AS created_on,
    max(updated_on) AS updated_on,
    max(updated_by) FILTER (WHERE updated_on = max(updated_on)) AS updated_by,
    max(array_to_string(value_name, '||'::text)) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'name' )as name,
    max(array_to_string(value_num, '||'::text)) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'mobile_number') AS mobile_number,
    max(array_to_string(value_num, '||'::text)) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'office_number') AS office_number
FROM object_attributes   
GROUP BY object_key;
```

Pivoted table must be like:

| object_key | created_by | updated_on | updated_by | name | mobile_number | office_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 4/21/2021 | user2 | John | 4567865 | 2378783 |

`updated_by` should come from a row having highest `updated_on` date for each `object_key`.

But `FILTER (WHERE updated_on = max(updated_on))` is not working in the query.

Is there a way to select `updated_by` using the `updated_on` in the pivot?

Comment: Is there a possibility of multiple values of the same *object_key* and *attr_type*?

Comment: there is unique key on combined columns (object_key and attr_type)

Comment: The displayed table disagrees with the one disclosed in your fiddle, where `value_name` and `value_num` are array columns (among other things). Please remember to disclose *actual* table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) with every question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with a single `SELECT` combining window functions with `DISTINCT ON`:

Adapted to the table definition finally disclosed in [your fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0c71174e19ec62adfd38c6b5310ab093):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_key)
       object_key
     , first_value(created_by) OVER w AS created_by
     , updated_on
     , updated_by
     , min(array_to_string(value_name, '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'Name'         ) OVER w AS "Name"
     , min(array_to_string(value_num , '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'Mobile_number') OVER w AS "Mobile_number"
     , min(array_to_string(value_num , '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'Office_number') OVER w AS "Office_number"
--   , min(array_to_string(value_name, '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'status'       ) OVER w AS status  -- ??
FROM   object_attributes
WHERE  object_key IN (1,2)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY object_key ORDER BY updated_on)
ORDER  BY object_key, updated_on DESC NULLS LAST;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=94c8da02442f2dfad8fc177e70b89430)*

This works, because `DISTINCT ON` is applied *after* window functions. Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

We can use the `FILTER` clause in aggregate window functions. See:

- [Conditional lead/lag function PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796929/conditional-lead-lag-function-postgresql/41797399#41797399)
- [How to group timestamps into islands (based on arbitrary gap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045788/how-to-group-timestamps-into-islands-based-on-arbitrary-gap/55065060#55065060)

The `WINDOW` clause is optional to shorten the code, you can spell it our 4x as well, same result.

Why you might need `NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

Related:

- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group/25173081#25173081)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: This should be accepted as this is the best answer.  I have deleted mine.

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter
Thanks for response. sry, I should have shared table structure first. 
I was getting error ``` function string_agg(integer[], unknown) does not exist``` . I checked your code. Updated the table creation script in db<>fiddle.
please look into db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0c71174e19ec62adfd38c6b5310ab093)
your query also giving same error

Comment: @Hari: I updated accordingly. (That's why you should provide your table definition with every question.)

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter: Thanks. I have added another field `created_on` in table. Pivot `created_on` must have least value of `created_on` for each object. so i added `first_value(created_on) over (PARTITION BY object_key order by created_on asc)` . now query has two `partitions by` with different order by (it may slow query perf). Can we re-write query in better way

Comment: Consider `last_value(created_on) over w` instead.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use window function `first_value`:

```
 SELECT 
    object_key,
    max(created_on) AS created_on,
    max(updated_on) AS updated_on,
    first_value(updated_by) over(order updated_on desc) AS updated_by,
    max(array_to_string(value_name,'||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'name' )as name,
    max(array_to_string(value_num, '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'mobile_number') AS mobile_number,
    max(array_to_string(value_num, '||')) FILTER (WHERE attr_type = 'office_number') AS office_number
FROM object_attributes   
GROUP BY object_key;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "updated_by" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function